# Performing segue for tableview in a page with multiple containerview and tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

I have a *viewcontroller* which embed several `containerview` and `tableview`, details as follows:

[image]

3 containerviews embed with tabbarcontroller, 2 containerviews embed with viewcontroller, 1 tableview

The tableview in this page is used for showing search results, and I want to add segue for this search results. However, when everything done, a **warning** message shown...

> Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x10794d8e8) to
>   'ACROSS_Bus.Search2' (0x1042970f8).

And the error code...

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "infoshows", sender: book0[indexPath.row].bookID)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let destination = segue.destination as! Search2

        destination.searchfromindex = searchwords.text!
    }
```

"Search2" is the page I want to show after click on the tableviewcell, and the identifier of segue is "infoshow". I think it may due to crash with tabbarviewcontroller. What can I do for this error? Thanks for your help and your tolerance of my poor English.

Comment: before performing segue you have to check if the identifier is same as of your segue  like In prepare check 'if segue.identifier == "infoshow" then perform/set params'